# PHP Namespace XML Array Issue

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Hello I am using the NOAA buoy RSS feed to create and insert variables into Mysql. There is a tag entitled:

```
<georss:point>45.565 -34.123</georss:point>
```

Which I have broken out as such:

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents($feed_url); 
$xmlString = str_replace('georss:point','point',$xmlString);  
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString); 
$items = $xml->xpath('channel/item'); 
$closeItems = array(); foreach($items as $item) 
{     
$latlng = explode(' ',trim($item->point));
$lat = $latlng[0];
$lng = $latlng[1];  
}
```

However the issue that I am running into, the variables for $lat and $lng are the same for all the feed articles. Each article will have a unique $lat and $lng, so I know I am doing something wrong here. Thanks Again,

Comment: Can you post the code that compares or outputs the values of `$lat` and `$lng`, as well as any intervening code that may alter their values?

Comment: Also, do you mean that the two variable values match each other, or that `$lat` is always one value and `$lng` is another, but they are the same for every record?

Comment: Hi George, the first record returned is Ship - 1969-12-31 19:00:00
lat=39.933 lng=-75.142 and the second record is Station 44065 - Entrance To New York Harbor lat=39.933 lng=-75.142 Notice the name is different but the lat and lng variables are the same

Comment: Replacing the `georss` namespace is just lazy. SimpleXML is capable of dealing with namespaces, see http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php#example-4737

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
foreach($items as $item) 
{     
    $latlng = explode(' ',trim($item->point));
    $lat = $latlng[0];
    $lng = $latlng[1];  
}
```

You assign the variables for each record, but never use them inside the loop. Assuming you have more code after the loop, that code will always receive only the last values assigned for `$lat` and `$lng`.

To correct the problem, place your record-specific code within the `foreach()` loop:

```
foreach($items as $item) 
{     
    $latlng = explode(' ',trim($item->point));
    $lat = $latlng[0];
    $lng = $latlng[1];
    // Do something with $lat and $lng here  
}
```

Comment: Hi George, doesnt seem to want to work for me. Perhaps I am not understanding correctly. Here is what I placed: foreach($items as $item, $lat as $latlng[0], $lng as $latlng[1])

Comment: @matt colley: Please see my updated answer for a description of the place to insert your code.